# UITableViewCell animate improperly at the very first time

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview, core-animation

I'm actually going to DELETE a cell on `aTableView` when a cell on `bTableView` is deselected. And also, I'm using `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController` just because there'r lots of things on my app, and for sure, I've adopted `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource`.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            if (tableView == bTableView) { ......
            MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [convertResultTableView beginUpdates];
            // some data updates stuff..

            [UIView beginAnimations:@"quitRotation" context:NULL];
            CATransform3D rotation;
            rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation((70.0 * M_PI) / 180, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            cell.layer.transform = rotation;
            cell.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(-1, 0.5);
            cell.alpha = 0;
            cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
            [UIView commitAnimations];
            [convertResultTableView endUpdates];
```

**The problem is the cells animate proper only when it animate at the second, third, forth.. time but NOT the first time. (which means it appear, disappear, appear and disappear <- this time)**

It still do some animation but it is just not as what I expected, and there'r a lot different between that WRONG animation and the proper animation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do this animation in method cellForRowAtIndexPath

Something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
   [tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  if([self.selectedIndexPath isEqual: indexPath]) {
    // do the animation  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm sorry about that I didn't mentioned that I'm actually going to DELETE a cell on `aTableView` when a cell on `bTableView` is deselected. And also, I'm using `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController` just because there'r lots of things on my app, and sure, I've adopted `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource`. Anyway, can you briefly describe why should I do the animation in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` ? Thanks!

Comment: Because, cell is something, that you should not touch outside the method cellForRowAtIndexPath. While you are scrolling, cells are automatically released from the memory, and before they are shown method cellForRowAtIndexPath is setting up the cell. If you need to delete some cells from the first tableview, simple delete the item from the data source array and reload table.

Comment: Got that, I will give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

Really a silly mistake!

**Here's my mistake:**
My `aTableView` will do some animation when first show, but my code have some silly mistake so that only my first row of cell of the `aTableView` do the animate, therefore,   cell.layer.position will be different. However, after it disappear and appear again, the cell.layer.position all go to the right place because the code is right, so it works when it's 2th, 3rd... time.

**How I found the mistake:** I just do `NSLog(...);` to log basically all the property of cell.layer because I'm really new to `CoreAnimation`, fortunately, my first try is  cell.layer.position, and I found the mistake immediately.